# How to make godoc link to source on github

Tags: github, go, godoc

On the godoc site, most libraries (http://godoc.org/github.com/beego/memcache for example) link directly to the source on github. When I run the godoc tool locally, this is not the case. We also have a local godoc server for our team, and it similarly does not link to the source on github. Our code is stored on github, and is organized accordingly (ie, github.com/mycompany/packagename). Is there a way to tell the godoc tool to link to code on github, even if it's in a private repo?

Comment: The website http://godoc.org and the godoc tool are not the same. godoc.org is not directly powered by the godoc tool.

Comment: I figured the docs on the godoc site were generated with the godoc tool, and there then must be a way to compile the godoc in a way that links to github. Am I wrong in these assumptions? Are the docs on the godoc.org site some custom markup?

Comment: godoc.org and godoc the cmd are **different**, your assumtions are wrong. And no, the docs at godoc.org are not some special markup, they are retrieved by the same mechanism godoc the cmd uses. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/_rbVuzl-OqA/N_xoNaD4kAoJ

Comment: Also see the source code for godoc.org - https://github.com/golang/gddo - if you're curious as to its workings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [godoc (Go Doc Dot Org)](https://github.com/golang/gddo) generates its own links to the source.

You can see that generation in [`gddo-server/template.go#L49-L62`](https://github.com/golang/gddo/blob/625df2a39320c2ca472463fdcdcb7320345521fe/gddo-server/template.go#L49-L62) `SourceLink()`.